# How insert the dataframe output to mysql

Tags: python, pandas, pymysql

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
db = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test123', 'world')
df1 = pd.read_sql('select * from country limit 5', db)
df1
```

I need to create a table name with `country2` and update the df1 out to `country2`

Comment: pandas has `to_sql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Pandas `to_sql` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). This should work for you:

```
import mymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
sql_table_name = 'country2'
engine = create_engine("mysql://testuser:test123@localhost:0/world") # creat engine
df1.to_sql(sql_table_name, engine) # add to table
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check out SqlAlchemy. Use SqlAlchemy to write a Mysql interation class. SqlAlchemy enables using python to connect database. Encoding your dataframe into a upsert sql string. And then use `cursor.execute(query_string)` to do the upsert.

Answer (score 0):

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pwd@hostname/db_name',
    connect_args={'auth_plugin': 'mysql_native_password'})

sample_sql_database = df.to_sql('table_name', con=engine)
```

There is an option to "append" the contends from data frame or "replace" also

```
sample_sql_database =  df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='replace')
sample_sql_database =  df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='append')
```

Reference :

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html